# How can I use pipe to stdin and stdout correctly

Tags: gcc, pipe, stdout, stdin, dup2

I am trying to compile assembly code on runtime using gcc. I'm getting the input from stdin (the assembly code) and outputting the result in binary format to stdout.
For some reason my program is getting stuck (I think because it is blocking while waiting for input from stdin).

Here is the code:

```
char* assemble(char* assembly_code){
        

char *binaryPath = "/usr/bin/gcc";
char *binary = "gcc";
char *arg1 = "-x";
char *arg2 = "assembler";
char *arg3 = "-";
char *arg4 = "-o";
char *arg5 = "/dev/stdout";
char *arg6 = "-nostdlib";
char *arg7 = "-Wl,--oformat=binary";
char *arg8 = "-m64";

char data[1024];
memset(data,0, 1024);

pid_t pid = 0;

int pipe_fd_1[2];
int pipe_fd_2[2];

int status;

pipe(pipe_fd_1);
pipe(pipe_fd_2);

pid = fork();

if (pid == 0){

    dup2(pipe_fd_1[0], fileno(stdin));
    dup2(pipe_fd_2[1], fileno(stdout));    

    close(pipe_fd_1[1]);
    close(pipe_fd_2[0]);
    
    execl(binaryPath, binary, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, (char*) NULL);

    close(pipe_fd_1[0]);
    close(pipe_fd_2[1]);

    exit(1);
}
close(pipe_fd_1[0]);
close(pipe_fd_2[1]);

write(pipe_fd_1[1], assembly_code, strlen(assembly_code));
read(pipe_fd_2[0], (void*)data, 1024);

close(pipe_fd_1[1]);
close(pipe_fd_2[0]);

printf("Received answer: %s\n", (char*)data);

kill(pid, SIGKILL); 
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

return data;



}
```

Comment: You need to close the pipe immediately after you have written your string, otherwise the forked program will just sit there and wait for more input.

Comment: Great! now it works! thanks!